# React could not export file from directory/index.js instead looking for directory.js

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am developing basic react app and following this [github react respository](https://github.com/reactjs/redux/tree/master/examples/todos).

Below is the folder structure inside within project directory (*/opt/rqt/*)

```
src/
├── App.css
├── actions.js
├── components
│   ├── App.js
│   ├── Footer.js
│   ├── Link.js
│   ├── Todo.js
│   └── TodoList.js
├── containers
│   ├── AddTodo.js
│   ├── FilterLink.js
│   └── VisibleTodoList.js
├── index.js
├── logo.svg
├── reducers
│   ├── index.js
│   ├── todos.js
│   └── visibilityFilter.js
└── registerServiceWorker.js
```

#### /src/index.js

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import { createStore } from 'redux'
import { Provider } from 'react-redux'
import App from './components/App'
import reducer from './reducers'
// import todoApp from './reducers' // trial 2
import './App.css'
import registerServiceWorker from './registerServiceWorker';

registerServiceWorker();

const store = createStore(reducer);
// const store = createStore(todoApp); // trial 2

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <App />
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

#### /src/reducers/index.js

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux'
import todos from './todos'
import visibilityFilter from './visibilityFilter'
const todoApp = combineReducers({
    todos,
    visibilityFilter
});

export default todoApp
```

but when run npm start it gives following error in browser

> Failed to compile ./src/reducers.js Module build failed: Error:
>   ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/opt/rqt/src/reducers.js'
>       at Error (native)

why react only finding file name *reducers.js* instead of looking for *reducers/index.js* ?

Also tried with appending `./reducers/` but not working

what is the issue here?

Comment: Have you tried: import reducer from './reducers/index.js'

Comment: Yes. but it gives different error *Error: Reducer "todos" returned undefined during initialization. If the state passed to the reducer is undefined, you must explicitly return the initial state. The initial state may not be undefined. If you don't want to set a value for this reducer, you can use null instead of undefined.*  that I understand that it now points to the right file but my query is why it is not navigating automatically?

Comment: I do not remember exactly. here is my [package.json](https://pastebin.com/8J8PNan8)

Comment: that tree structure in question is inside of  **src** folder

Comment: now working fine when appended  `/`  as  `import reducer from ./reducers/`.

Comment: Did you have a file called reducers.js before?

Comment: Yes I had */src/reducers.js* file earlier but moved it to another folder as I want to use  **reducers** directory.

Answer (score 3):

I encountered a similar issue when started with React. Apparently this is caused by in bug in React DOM. There is a similar [Github issue here](https://github.com/erikras/redux-form/issues/4073).

What I did is that I terminate the process and **re-install the dependencies** (`npm install`)

Then, it work with the code:

**/src/reducers/index.js**

```
export default combineReducers({
    // Some Code Here
})
```

And then, you can easily import it in **App.js** or **index.js**:

```
import rootReducer from "../reducers"
```

Thus, you can replace `rootReducer` with any name you like.